# Is there a better way to write this ActiveRecord Rails 4.2 query using scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm building a UI to let a user find a zoo by animal and/or by trainer for a Rails 4 application with postgres.

There are a series of animal checkboxes and a series of trainer checkboxes. A user may check multiple checkboxes in both the trainer and animal sections.

*here is the rails code I am using to build the query*

```
animal_ids = [1, 2, 3]
trainer_ids = [1, 2] 

# OR query - either an animal or trainer can be present to find a zoo
a = Zoo.includes(:animals).where(animals: { id: animal_ids}) 
b = Zoo.includes(:trainers).where(trainers: { id: trainer_ids})
zoos = a+b
```

This results in 4 sql queries in the console.  Is there a more efficient way to write this?  Should I use raw sql with an OR condition?

**model setup**

```
class Zoo < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :animals, through: zoo_animals
  has_many :trainers, through: zoo_trainers
  has_many :zoo_trainers
  has_many :zoo_animals
end  

class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zoos, through :zoo_animals
  has_many :zoo_animals
end  

class Trainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zoos, through :zoo_trainers 
  has_many :zoo_trainers
end  

class ZooAnimal < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :animal
  belongs_to :zoo
end

class ZooTrainer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zoo
  belongs_to :trainer
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify the `where` clause yourself:

```
Zoo.includes(:animals, :trainers).references(:animals, :trainers).where("animals.id IN (?) OR trainers.id IN (?)", animal_ids, trainer_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a scope to find `zoo`:

```
class Zoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :from_animal_and_trainer, -> (animal_ids, trainer_ids) {
    joins(:animals, :trainers).where(Animal.arel_table[:id].in(animal_ids)
                                      .or(Trainer.arel_table[:id].in(trainer_ids)))
  }
end
```

Then use it:

```
animal_ids = [1, 2, 3]
trainer_ids = [1, 2]
zoos = Zoo.from_animal_and_trainer(animal_ids,  trainer_ids)
```

Btw, this will generate just a single query, since we use `joins` in the above query